# When the VIEW table calculate or change the value?

Tags: spring, postgresql, view, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I create a View table, like

```
CREATE VIEW a AS SELECT b.kcu_id, sum(b.price), FROM b GROUP BY b.kcu_id
```

I create a view because my table contains too many rows, like 10000 or more. And it is too costly if we must sum that many rows every time get operation is called.
I use spring data jpa to get the data from the view. What I want to ask is, when I use the getPrice method to get the sum of prices, it is calculate the sum when I use the get method or the database calculate the sum when there are a change in column performance in b table in database?

For your info, price column is rarely change in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a "regular" view like you have in your example, the data will be calculated anew every time you query it. A view, after all, is just a slightly modified view of the data in the table at any given point.

You can have what they call "materialised views", which are more like a physical table that's updated from the underlying table periodically but you generally have to do that differently that with a normal "create view" command.

With PostgreSQL, the commands you're looking for are:

```
create materialized view
refresh materialized view
```

The former creates a materialised view in pretty much the same way as your `create view` and also populates the view with data (unless you've used the `with no data` clause). It also remembers the underlying query used to create the view (like *any* view does) so that you can update the data at some later point (which is what the `refresh` command above does).

By way of example, the following PostgreSQL code:

```
create table below (val integer);

insert into below values (42);
create materialized view above as select * from below;
insert into below values (99);

select * from below;
select * from above;

refresh materialized view above;
select * from above;
```

will materialise the view when the table contains only the `42` and later refresh it to include the `99` as well:

```
Underlying table 'below' with both data items:
| val |
|-----|
|  42 |
|  99 |

Materialised view 'above', created before the insert of 99:
| val |
|-----|
|  42 |

Materialised view 'above' after refreshing the view:
| val |
|-----|
|  42 |
|  99 |
```

Provided you're willing to live with the possibility that the data may be a little out of date, that's probably the best way to do it. Given your comment that the "price column is rarely change[d]", that may not be an issue.

However, I'm actually quite surprised that 10,000 rows is causing you an problem, it's not really *that* big a table. Hence you may want to look at other possible fixes, such as ensuring you have an index on the `kcu_id` column.